# when using both the rest and soap end points. I need to make the soap as the default one?

Tags: wcf, web-services, rest, soap, service

I need to use soap end point as the default one because i dont need the existing users to be disturbed..what is the change that i should do in the config?

I have two end points one for soap and one for rest services. I tried creating two separate services but still didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample:

```
<endpoint address="json/mycontract" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyContract" />
<endpoint address="soap/mycontract" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyContract" />
```

There is no such thing as a default endpoint from client point of view. The clients do consume the service contracts using the desired endpoints.

Comment: Thanks @Mihai for that info. But is there any possibility for the client to have the soap endpoint as a default one in his web config even when there are two end points?

Comment: You have to do it programmatic, get the endpoint from your config file. (http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2007/10/19/loading-the-wcf-configuration-from-different-files-on-the-client-side.aspx and http://mostlytech.blogspot.com/2007/11/programmatically-enumerate-wcf.html)

Comment: Thanks @Mihai for the instant reply